# ModelMapper mapping error for converting Set

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

i am getting error from postman during get request to get a AgentCustomerMappingEntity :  "ModelMapper mapping errors:\n\n1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter@36531f6d failed to convert org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet to java.util.Set.\n\n1 error". Below is entity
public class AgentCustomerMappingEntity {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
private UUID id;
@OneToOne
private ProcessEntity process;
@OneToOne
private AgentEntity agent;
@OneToMany
private Set<CustomerEntity> customers;
```

}.  customers are not getting mapped properly. any help would be appreciated.